# Should/do I have to export returning class returned by another exported class in Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, class, design-patterns, export, es6-modules

Consider the following module:

```
export class Bar {

    generateFoo() {
        return new Foo(1);
    }

}

class Foo {

    constructor(fooValue) {
        this.fooValue = fooValue;
    }

    doFoo() { console.log(this.fooValue); }

}
```

Should I export `Foo` too in any situation? Why/Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I export Foo too in any situation? Why/Why not?

The only reason to export something from a module is if you want code from outside to be able to call it or reference it directly.  If the only way you want your clients to be able to create `Foo` objects is by calling `bar.generateFoo()`, then there is no reason to export `Foo`.  In Javascript, you can fully reference all `Foo` methods on an already constructed object without exporting the class itself.

If, on the other hand, you want some client of your module to be able to directly instantiate a `Foo` object with `new Foo(someValue)`, then you would need to export `Foo` to make that possible.

Exporting a class is exporting the constructor function.  So, you need to do that export if you want someone to be able to call the constructor directly (e.g. construct a new object with `new Foo()`).  If they don't need to call the constructor directly, then you don't need to export it.